# How to dynamic, handle nested WHERE AND/OR queries using Rails and SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I'm currently building a feature that requires me to loop over an hash, and for each key in the hash, dynamically modify an SQL query.

The actual SQL query should look something like this:

```sql
select * from space_dates d
    inner join space_prices p on p.space_date_id = d.id
    where d.space_id = ?
    and d.date between ? and ?
    and (
        (p.price_type = 'monthly' and p.price_cents <> 9360) or
        (p.price_type = 'daily' and p.price_cents <> 66198) or
        (p.price_type = 'hourly' and p.price_cents <> 66198) # This part should be added in dynamically
    )
```

The last `and` query is to be added dynamically, as you can see, I basically need only one of the conditions to be true but not all.

```
query = space.dates
      .joins(:price)
      .where('date between ? and ?', start_date, end_date)

# We are looping over the rails enum (hash) and getting the key for each key value pair, alongside the index

SpacePrice.price_types.each_with_index do |(price_type, _), index|
  amount_cents = space.send("#{price_type}_price").price_cents
  query = if index.positive? # It's not the first item so we want to chain it as an 'OR'
            query.or(
              space.dates
               .joins(:price)
               .where('space_prices.price_type = ?', price_type)
               .where('space_prices.price_cents <> ?', amount_cents)
             )
           else
             query # It's the first item, chain it as an and
               .where('space_prices.price_type = ?', price_type)
               .where('space_prices.price_cents <> ?', amount_cents)
           end
end
```

The output of this in rails is:

```
SELECT "space_dates".* FROM "space_dates"
  INNER JOIN "space_prices" ON "space_prices"."space_date_id" = "space_dates"."id"
  WHERE "space_dates"."space_id" = $1 AND (
   (
     (date between '2020-06-11' and '2020-06-11') AND
     (space_prices.price_type = 'hourly') AND (space_prices.price_cents <> 9360) OR
     (space_prices.price_type = 'daily') AND (space_prices.price_cents <> 66198)) OR
     (space_prices.price_type = 'monthly') AND (space_prices.price_cents <> 5500)
   ) LIMIT $2
```

Which isn't as expected. I need to wrap the last few lines in another set of round brackets in order to produce the same output. I'm not sure how to go about this using ActiveRecord.

It's not possible for me to use `find_by_sql` since this would be dynamically generated SQL too.

Comment: I can see no difference between the generated query and the first one, except that (date between '2020-06-11' and '2020-06-11')  has been put inside the round brackets. You said that the last few lines need to have another set of round brackets. Could you clarify?

Comment: Hey, yeah so that query didn't work cause of the brackets but I actually managed to solve it. I'll post my answer so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to solve this in about an hour using Arel with rails

```rb
 dt = SpaceDate.arel_table
 pt = SpacePrice.arel_table

 combined_clauses = SpacePrice.price_types.map do |price_type, _|
   amount_cents = space.send("#{price_type}_price").price_cents
   pt[:price_type]
     .eq(price_type)
     .and(pt[:price_cents].not_eq(amount_cents))
 end.reduce(&:or)

  space.dates
    .joins(:price)
    .where(dt[:date].between(start_date..end_date).and(combined_clauses))
  end
```

And the SQL output is:

```sql
SELECT "space_dates".* FROM "space_dates"
INNER JOIN "space_prices" ON "space_prices"."space_date_id" = "space_dates"."id" 
WHERE "space_dates"."space_id" = $1
AND "space_dates"."date" BETWEEN '2020-06-11' AND '2020-06-15'
AND (
  ("space_prices"."price_type" = 'hourly'
   AND "space_prices"."price_cents" != 9360
   OR "space_prices"."price_type" = 'daily'
   AND "space_prices"."price_cents" != 66198)
  OR "space_prices"."price_type" = 'monthly'
  AND "space_prices"."price_cents" != 5500
) LIMIT $2
```

What I ended up doing was:

1. Creating an array of clauses based on the enum key and the `price_cents`
2. Reduced the clauses and joined them using `or`
3. Added this to the main query with an `and` operator and the `combined_clauses`